# Runtime error 424 Object required -- VBA + Internet Explorer = Web Log in

Tags: vba, excel

I am attemting to log into a website using VBA and Internet Explorer. This is causing a Run TIme error 424 "Object Required".

Here is my code. Looking for your expert advise.

```
Sub Website()

  Dim IE As Object, Doc As Object, UserName As Object, Password As Object, strCode As String

  Set IE = New InternetExplorerMedium
  IE.Visible = True
  IE.Navigate "http://appln.ABC.com/index.epl"

  Do While IE.ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

  Set Doc = IE.Document

  Set UserName = Doc.getElementById("login_usr")
  UserName.Value = "ABCDE"

  Set Password = Doc.getElementById("login_password")
  Password.Value = "ABCDE"

  Set btnLogin = Doc.getElementById("Login")
  btnLogin.Click

End Sub
```

Comment: Error is on which line?

Comment: Hi Tim, Error is appearing after "Set Doc = IE.Document"

Answer (score 1):

Did you try the method set forth in this example?

[Fill user name and password in a webpage using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24038230/fill-user-name-and-password-in-a-webpage-using-vba)

I think you need to

```
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
```

In your code you aren't actually creating an object, you're just declaring it.

**EDIT**

Maybe bypass the usage of your Doc object:

```
Sub Website()

  Dim IE As Object, UserName As Object, Password As Object, strCode As String

  Set IE = New InternetExplorerMedium
  IE.Visible = True
  IE.Navigate "http://appln.ABC.com/index.epl"

  Do While IE.ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

  Set UserName = IE.Document.getElementById("login_usr")
  UserName.Value = "ABCDE"

  Set Password = IE.Document.getElementById("login_password")
  Password.Value = "ABCDE"

  Set btnLogin = IE.Document.getElementById("Login")
  btnLogin.Click

End Sub
```

In the linked example they only used one object, it seems you don't need to create objects for everything you're doing.  So, you could probably get away with:

```
Sub Website()

  Dim IE As Object

  Set IE = New InternetExplorerMedium
  IE.Visible = True
  IE.Navigate "http://appln.ABC.com/index.epl"

  Do While IE.ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

  With IE.Document
      .getElementById("login_usr").Value = "ABCDE"
      .getElementById("login_password").Value = "ABCDE"
      .getElementById("Login").Click
  End With

End Sub
```

You might also add a second do while loop for ready state, as in that linked example.

Comment: `Set IE = New InternetExplorerMedium` creates the object

Comment: Yes I did try that. For some reason I was forced to use "Set IE = New InternetExplorerMedium" instead of "Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.application")"

Comment: Tried the new code -- still getting "Object required" error!! Driving me crazy!!!!

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub website()
    Dim ie As Variant
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    ie.Visible = True
    ie.navigate "http://appln.ABC.com/index.epl"
    Do While ie.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
    ie.document.getElementById("login_usr").Value = "ABCDE"
    ie.document.getElementById("login_password").Value = "ABCDE"
    ie.document.getElementById("Login").Click
End Sub
```

Comment: I didn't look at your answer until I was done with mine, looks like pretty much the same thing.  Can you explain the purpose of the `IHTMLElement`?  I don't see it being used.

Comment: Hi karthick - When I try your code, I am getting "Automation error: The object invoked has disconnected from its clients" error.

Comment: @n8. IHTML has never used here hence removed as per your advice.Thanks

Comment: Tried the code with no result. Error --> "Automation Error. Interface is unknown."

Comment: try this `Set IE = New InternetExplorerMedium` instead of `Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")` and it requires Microsoft Internet Controls

Comment: That's what my answer does and it's not working for OP

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how but when I set

```
 IE.Visible = False
```

I don't get the error anymore. Please do try and if possible explain why it happens..

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and found another possible solution. I was checking `IE.Busy` in my wait loop. I ended up with the same error. It seems that Excel is not finding a `Document` element in the IE object initially. When I would wait about 1 minute then continue the code, the error would stop happening. I found the following code gave enough time to ensure the document element was created and Excel could find it to start finding elements.

```vb
Do While IE.Busy
    Do Events
Loop

Do While IE.readyState <> 4
    Do Events
Loop
```