# Using VBA to Log in to a website and clear previous login credentials

Tags: vba, excel

I am currently using this [Fill user name and password in a webpage using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24038230/fill-user-name-and-password-in-a-webpage-using-vba) code to log in to a website but I am running into an issue. Since the username and password is already saved on the browser it is adding the uid/pass again and creating an error in the login process. Is there a way I can add some code to clear any previously input uid/pass?

```
Sub test()
 ' open IE, navigate to the desired page and loop until fully loaded
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
my_url = "https://hb2.bankleumi.co.il/e/Login.html"

With ie
    .Visible = True
    .Navigate my_url
    .Top = 50
    .Left = 530
    .Height = 400
    .Width = 400

Do Until Not ie.Busy And ie.readyState = 4
    DoEvents
Loop

End With

' Input the userid and password
ie.Document.getElementById("uid").Value = "testID"
ie.Document.getElementById("password").Value = "testPW"

' Click the "Search" button
ie.Document.getElementById("enter").Click

Do Until Not ie.Busy And ie.readyState = 4
    DoEvents
Loop
 End Sub
```

Comment: first check if the value already is the current username, in which case, just move on and click; otherwise try to clear it out with a `.Value = ""` line?

Comment: @ScottHoltzman  Brilliant. Clearing it using .value= "" worked perfectly. Thank you very much! If you post it as an answer I would be more than happy to accept it so the thread can close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can test if the currently loaded username is the same, and if so, just click, otherwise, clear out the existing username with a `.Value = ""`

```
If ie.Document.getElementById("uid").Value = "testID" Then
Else
  ie.Document.getElementById("uid").Value = ""
  ie.Document.getElementById("password").Value = ""
  ie.Document.getElementById("uid").Value = "testID"
  ie.Document.getElementById("password").Value = "testPW"
End If
```