# VBA auto login unsuccessful Error 91

Tags: html, vba, dom

Basically, I would like to auto login a website, i could find the id= "username" so i could use IE.Document.getElementById("username").value = "xxxxxxx" However, it does not work since there is no value input on Dom. Instead, when i try to edit on HTML DOM by creating new attribute - Value = "xxxxxxx", it shows the username input on website. I wonder if i could transfer this into vba and finish the auto login. Thanks a lot! Error 91 shown regarding to this case

```
Sub Nomuralogin()

Dim IE As InternetExplorer
Dim Stockcode As String
Dim Stocktext As String, Textchange As String
Dim HTMLDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim IEField As HTMLInputElement
Dim i As Integer, nAsset As Integer

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Navigate "https://www.nomuranow.com/portal/site/nnextranet/en/#curtain- login"
IE.Visible = True

Do While IE.Busy Or IE.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
DoEvents
Loop

Set HTMLDoc = IE.Document
Set IEField = HTMLDoc.getElementById("username")

IEField.Value = "abc@gmail.com"
'HTMLDoc.all.item("username").value = "abc@gmail.com" 
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:03")
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

IE.Quit

Set IE = Nothing
End Sub
```

Pic 1 shows there is no Value input:
[image: Pic 1]

Pic 2 shows I have created property and added a value input:
[image: Pic 2]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fill user name and password in a webpage using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24038230/fill-user-name-and-password-in-a-webpage-using-vba)

Comment: not the same at all. The problem is IE.Document.getElementbyId("username").Value doesn't work at all coz there is no value input on the html dom. I have to create one by myself

Comment: You have not explained that well. Show us your code. You don't even ask a question, and finish telling us that it works when edit the DOM. So it is completely unclear what you're asking gor.

Comment: Showed my code. Please kindly advise. Thanks

Comment: So HTMLDoc.all.item("username").value doesn't work? That's because it should be IEField.Value = ... Just like the duplicate. Also "Doesn't work" isn't helpful, try providing the error message instead. Good luck!